# In Spring Boot 3.0.3, unable to create beans of class annotated by @Component annotation

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, spring-boot-test

**In pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>SpringBootDataJpaStoredProcedureEx</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>SpringBootDataJpaStoredProcedureEx</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**In application.properties**

```
# database properties
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/springbootdatalearndb
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=123456

# spring data jpa properties
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

**In Employee.java**

```
package com.example.models;

import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "sp_employee_table")
public class Employee {
    @Id
    private Integer empId;
    private String empName;
    private String empDesg;
    private String empDept;
    private Double empSal;
}
```

**In EmployeeRepository.java**

```
package com.example.repositories;

import com.example.models.Employee;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Integer> {
}
```

**In DataInsertRunner.java**

```
package com.example.runners;

import com.example.models.Employee;
import com.example.repositories.EmployeeRepository;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@Slf4j
public class DataInsertRunner implements CommandLineRunner {
    @Autowired
    private EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        log.info("DataInsertRunner execution started.");
        employeeRepository.save(new Employee(101, "SAM", "Lead", "DEV", 86500.0));
        employeeRepository.save(new Employee(102, "RAM", "MGR", "DEV", 96000.0));
        employeeRepository.save(new Employee(103, "SYED", "ASSOCIATE", "QA", 32500.0));
        employeeRepository.save(new Employee(104, "ABD", "MGR", "BA", 55500.0));
        log.info("DataInsertRunner execution completed.");
    }
}
```

**In StarterClass (SpringBootDataJpaStoredProcedureExApplication.java)**

```
package com.example;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootDataJpaStoredProcedureExApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootDataJpaStoredProcedureExApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

**Console:**

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.0.3)

2023-02-25T14:48:44.900+05:30  INFO 13732 --- [  restartedMain] gBootDataJpaStoredProcedureExApplication : Starting SpringBootDataJpaStoredProcedureExApplication using Java 17.0.4.1 with PID 13732 (G:\Java\IntelliJ Workspace\Learning\Spring Boot By Raghu\Spring Boot Data\SpringBootDataJpaStoredProcedureEx\target\classes started by himan in G:\Java\IntelliJ Workspace\Learning\Spring Boot By Raghu\Spring Boot Data\SpringBootDataJpaStoredProcedureEx)
2023-02-25T14:48:44.903+05:30  INFO 13732 --- [  restartedMain] gBootDataJpaStoredProcedureExApplication : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-02-25T14:48:44.954+05:30  INFO 13732 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2023-02-25T14:48:45.382+05:30  INFO 13732 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2023-02-25T14:48:45.400+05:30  INFO 13732 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 10 ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
2023-02-25T14:48:45.785+05:30  INFO 13732 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2023-02-25T14:48:45.837+05:30  INFO 13732 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.1.7.Final
2023-02-25T14:48:46.177+05:30  INFO 13732 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2023-02-25T14:48:46.600+05:30  INFO 13732 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Added connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@27cbf856
2023-02-25T14:48:46.602+05:30  INFO 13732 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2023-02-25T14:48:46.657+05:30  INFO 13732 --- [  restartedMain] SQL dialect                              : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
2023-02-25T14:48:46.975+05:30  INFO 13732 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2023-02-25T14:48:46.987+05:30  INFO 13732 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2023-02-25T14:48:47.136+05:30  INFO 13732 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2023-02-25T14:48:47.157+05:30  INFO 13732 --- [  restartedMain] gBootDataJpaStoredProcedureExApplication : Started SpringBootDataJpaStoredProcedureExApplication in 2.637 seconds (process running for 3.445)
2023-02-25T14:48:47.165+05:30  INFO 13732 --- [ionShutdownHook] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2023-02-25T14:48:47.169+05:30  INFO 13732 --- [ionShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2023-02-25T14:48:47.179+05:30  INFO 13732 --- [ionShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.

Process finished with exit code 0
```

As you can see when I am using Spring Boot-3.0.3, there is no bean created for runner i.e., DataInsertRunner and it is not even called at application startup.
But when I am using Spring Boot-3.0.2, It is working fine.
I have checked documentation of Spring Boot-3.0.3 for any update, but did not find anything new about runner or bean creation.
So, please suggest me if any update have been made related to runner or bean creation.

[Link of above project](https://github.com/dev-himanshu/IssueSpringBoot3.0.3/tree/main/SpringBootDataJpaStoredProcedureEx) using spring boot 3.0.3

[Link of above project](https://github.com/dev-himanshu/ReferenceSpringBoot3.0.2/tree/main/SpringBootDataJpaStoredProcedureEx) using spring boot 3.0.2

I am trying to insert data into mysql database at application startup using runner.

Comment: I have also created this issue in spring boot github repository. Link: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/34380

Comment: Because the bean life cycle finished after save data into database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior is due to [a regression](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/30031) in Spring Framework 6.0.5. You can work around the problem by not having any spaces in your application's path. Alternatively, downgrading to Spring Framework 6.0.4 should also work.

Comment: Yes, now it is fixed with the release of Spring Boot 3.0.4